# Hibernate @Formula generates additional table when loading collection in Hibernate 4.0.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss7.x, wildfly-8

We have a Country table, which references StateRegion table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MDM_COUNTRY")
public class Country extends AuditedEntity {

private Set<StateRegion> stateRegions;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @BatchSize(size=100)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_CODE", referencedColumnName="COUNTRY_CODE")
    public Set<StateRegion> getStateRegions() {
        return stateRegions;
    }
}
```

As you can see it is using non-primary key as a join column. When just loading countries it works fine, but when Country is referenced in some other entity, for example Department, then if Country without any StateRegions is selected `ClassCastException` is thrown, because Hibernate tries to evaluate getCountryCode() on a country id (Long) for some reason.

Some investigations showed, that using non-primary key as join column is not very good idea, so in order to fix this, I've changed StateRegions list mapping to use `@Formula`:

```
@Formula("(SELECT region FROM StateRegion region WHERE region.countryCode = countryCode)")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = StateRegion.class)
public Set<StateRegion> getStateRegions() {
    return stateRegions;
}
```

Which works fine with Hibernate 4.3.7 (since we are also in process of migrating from Jboss 7.1 to Wildfly 8.2.1 - I have already Wildfly (Hibernate 4.3.7), but other environments are still running with JBoss (where Hibernate 4.0.1 is in use)).

For some reason, Hibernate 4.0.1 generates following SQL:

```
select <columns_were_cut> from MDM_COUNTRY_MDM_STATE_REGION stateregio0_ inner join MDM_STATE_REGION stateregio1_ on stateregio0_.stateRegions_id=stateregio1_.id where stateregio0_.Country_id=?
```

which is kind of not, what is written in @Formula description and which, apparently fails, with

```
ERROR: relation "mdm_country_mdm_state_region" does not exist
```

because there is really no such table.

Any idea how to make my @Formula definition compatible with Hibernate 4.0.1?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Casey, I am not in the project anymore, but if I remember correctly then I fixed it by introducing proper primary key (id) on country table and made state_region referencing country via country_id (FK), instead of country code, then fixed mapping. But if you can use newer version of Hibernate then it should also work with a Formula. Hope that helps.

Comment: I faced the same problem with @Formula with the latest version of Hibernate org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.1.Final and 5.5.3.Final.
So is there way to fix @Formula?